# What happens if you click disabled UIButton

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, ibaction, viewdidload

The title doesn't have enough details so let me explain what I mean. So if I disable a UIbutton in my viewDidLoad func (and just to check i'm doing it right I have my code below for disabling) but then I do a drag and drop IBAction function in the same class, if it's unlickable but then I have that, what happens. Does it still stay unclickable?

I would test myself but currently can't test as i'm on school computers and i'm waiting for a sys admin to allow access to the debug processes.

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By disabling the button, you are essentially making inactive. This means a few different things for different elements of the button. You can read more about it in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton).

In regards to ctrl+dragging into the code, it will not react to any actions. The whole point of it is that it basically becomes 'unclickable'. So for example, if you have default layout, it will grey it out and not react (style-wise) when it is clicked. This is the same with any IBAction on the button. It's commonly used to disabled a button until something is satisfied, for example, in a form that all slots are filled etc.

Here's a picture of the default one disabled.

[image: Default disabled Button]